# how to redirect user and admin into respective form in java after pressing login button

Tags: java, swing

how to redirect user login into respective page, i have mainmenu form for admin and usermainmenu form for user. i tried this below codes but i get only one usermainmenu no matter i change

```
con = Connect.ConnectDB();
    String sql = "SELECT User_Type as 'Type', username, password FROM Users, User_Type WHERE Users.User_Type_ID = User_Type.User_Type_ID and username=? and password =? and (User_Type='admin' &&  User_Type='user');";

    //String sql= "select * from Users where username= '" + txtUserName.getText() + "' and password ='" + txtPassword.getText() + "'";
    try {

        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtUserName.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtPassword.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        String username = txtUserName.getText();
        String password = txtPassword.getText();

        while (!rs.next()) {
            if (username.trim().equals(txtUserName.getText().equals(username)) && password.trim().equals(txtPassword.getText().equals(password) && username.trim().equals(User_Type))) {

                UserMainMenu frm = new UserMainMenu();
                frm.setVisible(true);
                rs.close();
            } else {
                MainMenu frm = new MainMenu();
                frm.setVisible(true);
                rs.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: even after i remove it completly. it redirect me into                                 MainMenu frm=new MainMenu();
                   frm.setVisible(true);                                                                           and even if i change user

Comment: that shows it skip enclosed if statement and jump into else enclosed statement

Comment: `if` block is completely wrong. You checking same value with same value, though what is this at the end.  `username.trim().equals(User_Type)` seems to always return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You call `rs.close()` everytime. When you close `ResultSet`, you can't still iterate over it. Close it **after** you are done with checking. Also I believe `while(!rs.next())` should be `while(rs.next())`. The former means that the condition will be **true**, if `rs` contains **no** data.

edit: ..wait, I'm not sure I understand what you want to accomplish. Above was written having in mind that you want to iterate over whole `ResultSet`. And you probably still do.

---

edit4: I know what it is.

Inside your `while` loop, look at what Strings are you actually comparing. You are not using data from your `ResultSet`. Oh boy, I got confused by this:

`firststring.trim().equals(otherString.equals(firstString))`.

`equals()` returns `boolean` `true` or `false`, so basically you were checking if your string is equal to true/false. And in this case it is always `false`.

```
if ( rs.getString(1).equals(User_Type) && rs.getString(2).equals(txtUserName.getText()) && rs.getString(3).equals(txtPassword.getText()) )
```

And then you have to provide `else if` for checking if what it found was an `Admin` user. Otherwise what comes in `else` block will be invoked every time the first condition was `false`.

I would write it as:

```
    String username = txtUserName.getText().trim();
    String password = txtPassword.getText().trim();
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, username);
    pst.setString(2, password);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    final String User_Type = "user";
    final String Admin_Type = "admin";

    String rsUserType, rsUsername, rsPassword;

    while (rs.next()) {
        rsUserType = rs.getString(1);
        rsUsername = rs.getString(2);
        rsPassword = rs.getString(3);

        if (rsUserType.equals(User_Type) && rsUsername.equals(username) && rsPassword.equals(password)) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                UserMainMenu frm = new UserMainMenu();
                frm.setVisible(true);
            });
            rs.close();

        } else if (rsUserType.equals(Admin_Type) && rsUsername.equals(username) && rsPassword.equals(password)) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                MainMenu frm = new MainMenu();
                frm.setVisible(true);
            });
            rs.close();
        }
    }
```

---

Also, your SQL query fails. I don't really know how your table looks, but give this a try:

```
SELECT UT.User_Type, U.username, U.password 
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN User_Type UT ON U.User_type_ID = UT.User_Type_ID
WHERE UT.User_Type LIKE "admin" OR  UT.User_Type LIKE "user" ;
```

In SQL there is `AND` instead of `&&`. If you want to combine data from two tables, you need to `JOIN` them. There are different `JOIN` types, depending on what you want to accomplish. `INNER JOIN` gives us an intersection of both tables, based `ON` given condition. This query will give you all users and admins. Anyway, you can also just search for one specific row in your SQL query, just as you tried to, and then only check `if(!rs.isClosed())`, then get User_Type you found to decide which menu to open.

Comment: the thing is i have two table one is for users and other user_type, then in my netbeans project i have created two different form that when user login will go into that page of usermainmenu and when admin login should go into mainmenu. but above codes what it gives me is only admin page even if i login as user and vise versa

Comment: not yet i try to change. and i think my comparison in if statement are confusing

Comment: now after this codeif (rs.getString(2).equals(txtUserName.getText()) && rs.getString(3).equals(txtPassword.getText()) && rs.getString(1).equals(User_Type))) {                      when i login i get catch expection error message prescribed but no form comes

Comment: do you think i should have a textfield for user_type so as to enter, i think of it because my login form has only username tetxfield and password field

Comment: @B.Daddy Is `User_Type` in your table an `integer` or a `string`? Because you need to call accordingly `rs.getInt()` or `rs.getString()`, also you can call `rs.getObject()` and cast it. And is `User_Type` you compare to in your if condition a globally defined variable? And of what type? What exception was thrown?

Comment: User_Type is a String in database i described it as varchar

Comment: @B.Daddy then getString() should get it. What exception was thrown?

Comment: catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed..Try again !","Access denied",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); 
          
            }

Comment: is there a trouble in netbeans if i have not created textfield for User_Type and yet i want to use it due to my sql statment String sql ="SELECT User_Type as 'Type', username, password FROM Users, User_Type WHERE Users.User_Type_ID = User_Type.User_Type_ID and username=? and password =? and (User_Type='admin' &&  User_Type='user');";

Comment: @bartisntsk this is structure of my tables      TABLE User_TYPE HAS FOLLOWING COLUMNS
User_Type_ID,
User_Type 



TABLE Users HAS FOLLOWING COLUMN
User_ID,
Name,
username,
password,
email,
User_Type_ID